# How to datePicker indexing realm and drawing chart in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, realm

Swift 3 , Realm, Charts

---

A screen has a DatePicker and BarChart

I want to

1) Pick a date
2) Indexing my realm database
3) Drawing a bar-chart

there already had a realm database

---

for indexing precise I separate date to YYYY~mm

```
class ChartsDatas: Object {
dynamic var date: Date = Date()

let dateYYYYFormat = DateFormatter()
let dateMMFormat = DateFormatter()
let dateddFormat = DateFormatter()
let datehhFormat = DateFormatter()
let datemmFormat = DateFormatter()
dynamic var dateYYYY: String = "2000"
dynamic var dateMM: String = "01"
dynamic var datedd: String = "01"
dynamic var datehh: String = "00"
dynamic var datemm: String = "00"

dynamic var count: Double = Double(0.0)

func dateLongToShort(orgDate:Date!){
    dateYYYYFormat.dateFormat = "YYYY"
    dateYYYY = dateYYYYFormat.string(from: orgDate)

    dateMMFormat.dateFormat = "MM"
    dateMM = dateMMFormat.string(from: orgDate)

    dateddFormat.dateFormat = "dd"
    datedd = dateddFormat.string(from: orgDate)

    datehhFormat.dateFormat = "hh"
    datehh = datehhFormat.string(from: orgDate)

    datemmFormat.dateFormat = "mm"
    datemm = datemmFormat.string(from: orgDate)
}
```

and drawing (This method is drawing newest ten datas)

```
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    let visitorCounts = getVisitorCountsFromDatabase() //read realm DB here

    var xAxisCount = visitorCounts.count 
    if xAxisCount > 10{
        xAxisCount = visitorCounts.count - 10
    }
    for i in xAxisCount..<visitorCounts.count {
        let timeIntervalForDate: TimeInterval = visitorCounts[i].date.timeIntervalSince1970
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(timeIntervalForDate), y: Double(visitorCounts[i].count))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
```

How to modify to drawing ten datas according to my chosen date

Thanks

Comment: Not an solution but you can use single `DateFormatter` instance with all function also correct `Year` formatter is `yyyy` not `YYYY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on in `getVisitorCountsFromDatabase()` but you can filter query results with predicate by specifying a date interval, see more in docs here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering

Comment: Solve my problem! What a convenient library, appreciate